# Python Django load data from text document

Tags: python, html, django

I am using python and django to make a website that should be able to load data from a text document and display it. Until now I have converted the data from txt format to html and loaded it to a div like so :

```
<div id='data'>
{% include "data.html" %}
</div>
```

Unfortunately when I hit refresh after I have modified data.html there is no update. I would like to be able to load the html file on every refresh

Comment: I think `include` is specifically made for django templates. I don't know the project requirements, but maybe the best is to save the file in the `FileSystemStorage` and present as a link in the page. Like in this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: @EduardoTolmasquim this is my first django project so I don't really know why I should avoid templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render out refreshed data from view via context is an easier way I think,
But if you have to use include in template, you can try to output a template name from your view, like {'data_template': 'data.html'} via context, then {% include data_template %} inside template.

Comment: I can't upvote you but yeah, your solution is easier and is what I ended up doing after you suggested it!